# Swift regex to match unicodes

Tags: ios, regex, swift, unicode

I am new to swift and want to match all the unicode strings using regex

For example:
var s=" emoji "
When I decoded the above string the result is:
"**\ud83d\ude00** emoji **\ud83d\ude00**"

I want to replace each emoji with say *

In java I used the regex as:
"[\uD800-\uDBFF\uDC00-\uDFFF]" and was working

In swift I am using the same regex but its replacing every character with *

I want the result as * emoji *

Help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unicode code point of the emoji you have shown is U+1F600.

([Unicode 9.0 Character Code Charts - Emoticons](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf))

And your regex pattern (which may work for UTF-16 representation) `[\uD800-\uDBFF\uDC00-\uDFFF]` matches all non-BMP characters -- U+10000...U+10FFFF, which contains most of all emojis but also contains huge non-emoji characters.

So, as you say "[\uD800-\uDBFF\uDC00-\uDFFF]" was working, the equivalent pattern in `NSRegularExpression` is `"[\\U00010000-\\U0010FFFF]"`.

```
var s=" emoji "
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[\\U00010000-\\U0010FFFF]", options: [])
let replaced = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(s, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<s.utf16.count), withTemplate: "*") //->"* emoji *"
```

---

(Addition)
To see Unicode code points in your string literal:

```
s.unicodeScalars.forEach {
    print(String(format: "U+%04X ", Int($0.value)))
}
```

For your example string, I get:

```
U+1F600 
U+0020 
U+0065 
U+006D 
U+006F 
U+006A 
U+0069 
U+0020 
U+1F600
```

Comment: Thanks!!
Can you also please tell how to replace the emoji with its unicode (1f600)

Comment: @Karthik, I added a short code snippet to check the Unicode code points in a String. If you want to generate something like "(1f6000) emoji (1f6000)", you need a little more bigger code than to put as an addition.